# custom ListView with text and image not showing up in Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm fairly new to Android and am trying to create a `ListView` with `ImageView` and `TextView` based on a custom adapter.

Somehow it won't seem to put the `ListView` on the screen when I try and run my app. No exceptions, though. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious. It would be great if someone could look over my code:

MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String[] countries = new String[] {"Germany", "USA", "Great Britain", "Japan", "Korea"};
    public static final int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.de, R.drawable.us, R.drawable.kr, R.drawable.jp, R.drawable.kr};
    ListView listView;
    List<MyListObject> values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        values = new ArrayList<MyListObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            MyListObject item = new MyListObject();
            item.setCountry(countries[i]);
            item.setImage(images[i]);
            values.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MySimpleArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListObject> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<MyListObject> values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceID, List<MyListObject> values) {
        super(context, resourceID, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        MyListObject rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);


        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryImage);


        holder.textView.setText(rowItem.getCountry());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public MyListObject getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

}
```

activity_my.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

rowlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/countryImage" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:text="@+id/countryName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyListObject.java:

```
public class MyListObject {
    private int image;
    private String country;

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call getCount method inside your custom adapter.And you have to return your array size there.

Comment: @pratik getCount is already override in the super class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `activity_my's` top most `linearlayout` should have `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute

In your `rowlayout` parent layout is `Horizontal LinearLayout` and `android:layout_width` for both `ImageView` and `TextView` is `fill_parent`.So, only `ImageView` is visible as in `LinearLayout` child place linearly one by one.Change `rowlayout` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/countryImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="countryName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You need to change your `Adapter` too

**MySimpleArrayAdapter**

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListObject> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<MyListObject> values;
    private int resourceID;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceID, List<MyListObject> values) {
        super(context, resourceID, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceID = resourceID;
        this.values = values;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;       
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceID, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyListObject rowItem = (MyListObject) values.get(position); 
        holder.textView.setText(rowItem.getCountry());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Most of all the if-clause in the adapter getView method confused the hell out of me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    //...

    return rowView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the orientation of your `LinearLayout` should be `vertical`. Default is `horizontal` . Add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

to the `LinearLayout` that contains the `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">
```

this will probably fix your issue with the *visualisation* . 
On the other side there are a couple of things you can change to improve the performance.

- In your layout you should provide `0dip` as height, since you are providing the weight. That will help the framework at "`onLayout`" time.
- `ArrayAdapter` has a concrete implementation of `getItem()`. You don't need to override it again, since you are already providing the dataset to the super class
- You are using the `ViewHolder` pattern in the wrong way. You should instantiate the `ViewHolder` once, when the convertView is null, looks for the views (as you already did) and call `convertView.setTag(viewHolderInstance)`,

Answer (score 0):

Here below os my custom adapter class, refer it and do like that way, it will surely work.

```
private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context context;
        JSONArray array;
        private Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.txtAuthorName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthorName);
                holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtTitle.setText(data.get(position).get("article_title"));
            holder.txtAuthorName.setText(data.get(position).get("author_name"));
            holder.txtDescription.setText(data.get(position).get("article_text"));





            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtAuthorName;
            TextView txtDescription;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your image width and height is not set to match constraints. Also, try updating the adapter in your main activity like this

```
public void updateAdapter(MyListObject _newObject){
    objectList.add(_newObject);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```